# express session doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, node.js, session, express

I am building a simple login function with express-session. However, the session object doest work. My logic is the req.session will get user_id when the user is created successfully. then validation will check the req.session, but the program doesn't go that way. The first console in login api will print userId property in req.session, but the req.session in validate doesn't. I don't know what was going on ?

```
app.use(session({
   secret : 'xxxyyy',
   cookie :{
     maxAge : 60*1000
   }
}));


app.get('/api/validate',function(req,res){
  console.log(req.session);
  var _userId = req.session._userId;
  if(_userId) {
    User.findByUserById(_userId,function(err,user){
        if (err) {
            res.json(401,{msg:err})
        } else{
            res.json(user);
        };
    })
  }else{
    res.json(401,null);
  };
})

app.post('/api/login',function(req,res){
  var email = req.body.email;
  if (email) {
    User.findByEmailOrCreate(email,function(err,user){
        if (err) {
            res.json(500,{msg:err})
        } else{

            req.session._userId = user._id;
            console.log(req.session)
            res.json(user)
        };
    })
  } else {
    res.json(403);
  };
})
```

My book says the session will be cleaned when server is restarted. 
My client side is Angular application like this

```
    $http({
        url : "/api/login",
        method : 'POST',
        data : {
            email : $scope.email
        }
    }).success(function(user){
        console.log(user)
        $scope.$emit('login',user);
        $location.path('/')
```

I don't think the path change will restart the server. Dose anyone tell me why ? or how do I improve the code.

Comment: Is this problem only happening before login or both before and after?

Comment: When the page load, validation is not working. when I  login the page, the page will successfully change the directory '/', however, after refreshing the page, I  will be moved to login page since the validation dosn't pass

Comment: have you tried setting the maxage higher?

Comment: Try setting a path: / and domain: yourdomain.com